# How to randomize the output from seq?

Tags: command-line, seq

I know I can use `seq` to generate a random list of numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4...

I want to get those numbers into a random order like 3, 1, 4, 2...

I know I can use `shuf` to shuffle the lines of a file. So I could use `seq` to write random numbers to a file and then use `shuf` to shuffle them -- or write some sort of shuffle function. But this seems needlessly complex. Is there a simpler way to randomize the items in an array with a single command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just pipe the output to `shuf`.

```
$ seq 100 | shuf
```

#### Example

```
$ seq 10 | shuf
2
6
4
8
1
3
10
7
9
5
```

If you want the output to be horizontal then pipe it to `paste`.

```
$ seq 10 | shuf | paste - -s -d ' '
1 6 9 3 8 4 10 7 2 5 

$ seq 10 | shuf | paste - -s -d ' '
7 4 6 1 8 3 10 5 9 2 

$ seq 10 | shuf | paste - -s -d ' '
9 8 3 6 1 2 10 4 7 5
```

Want it with commas in between? Change the delimiter to `paste`:

```
$ seq 10 | shuf | paste - -s -d ','
2,4,9,1,8,7,3,5,10,6
```

Comment: But you've gotta format somehow to get 'em on one line with commas. `echo $(seq 10 | shuf)` comes close but doesn't do the commas.

Comment: It's horizontal before `paste` ...

Comment: @mikeserv - changed it around.

Comment: Yeah. There you go. I didnt know `paste` did that. Thanks for teaching me. Have an upvote.

Comment: @mikeserv - yeah read through the site looking at either mine, Stephane's or Gilles A's using `join` and `paste`. Those 2 tools are extremely powerful.

Comment: Apparently. Ive seen Stephane do some cool stuff with `join.` One question in particular was  answered like 5 times with all of these multiline scripts and Stephane showed up a few hours later: "Thats what `join` is for: `join arg1 arg2`"

Comment: @mikeserv - yeah he has a knack for doing that 8-)

Comment: I use `xargs` instead of `paste` for that  ;)

Comment: @lzkata Screw `xargs`:  `| . /dev/stdin`

Comment: @Izkata - yeah `xargs` isn't the right tool to do this.

Comment: slm - i meant screw `xargs` in general. Look at the last part of my answer...

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a simpler way to randomize the items in an array with a
>   single command?

Assuming you have an array of decimal integers:

```
arr=(4 8 14 18 24 29 32 37 42)
```

You could use `printf` and `shuf` to randomize the elements of the array:

```
$ arr=($(printf "%d\n" "${arr[@]}" | shuf))
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
4 37 32 14 24 8 29 42 18
```

<sub><sup>(the above assumes you've not modified `$IFS`).</sup></sub>

---

If all that you need is random numbers between two integers, say `10` and `20`, you do not need any extra processes other than `shuf` by using the `-i` option:

```
$ shuf -i 10-20
12
10
20
14
16
19
13
11
18
17
15
```

Quoting from `man shuf`:

```
   -i, --input-range=LO-HI
          treat each number LO through HI as an input line
```

Comment: Shucks. I saw that too in `shuf --help` but i tried to use `shuf -i 1 10` without the intervening `-dash.` oh well, good work - have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf '%s, ' `seq 1 10 | shuf`
```

You don't even need a `for` loop.

#### OUTPUT

```
7, 3, 4, 10, 2, 9, 1, 8, 5, 6,
```

To get them in a shell array you do:

```
( set -- $(seq 1 10 | shuf) ; printf '%s, ' "$@" )
```

#### OUTPUT

```
5, 9, 7, 2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 10, 8,
```

And then they're in your shell array.

If you get them in the shell array, you don't even need `printf`:

```
( set -- $(seq 1 10 | shuf); IFS=, ; echo "$*" )
```

#### OUTPUT

```
9,4,10,3,1,2,7,5,6,8
```

By the way, `seq` and `printf` are kinda made for each other. For instance if I want to repeat a string 1000 times?

```
printf 'a string\n%.0b' `seq 1 1000`
```

#### OUTPUT

```
a string
```

... 999 `a string` lines later...

```
a string
```

Or...

```
printf 'a string,%.0b' `seq 1 10`
```

#### OUTPUT

```
a string,a string,a string,a string,a string,a string,a string,a string,a string,a string,
```

I want to execute a command 39 times?

```
printf 'echo "run %d"\n' `seq 1 39` | . /dev/stdin
```

#### OUTPUT

```
run 1
```

... 38 `run` lines later ...

```
run 39
```

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly, to generate a shuffled list of the decimal integers from `min` to `max`:

```
awk -v min=1 -v max=10 'BEGIN{
  for (i = min; i <= max; i++) a[i] = i
  srand()
  for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    j = int(rand() * (max - min + 1)) + min
    tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = tmp
  }
  for (i = min; i <= max; i++) print a[i]
}'
```

Beware that with many awk implementations, running that command twice within the same second will produce the same result (as `srand()` seeds the pseudo-random generator based on the current time).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `shuf` command to randomize output, e.g

```
%> for x in $(seq 1 10 | shuf); do echo -n "$x "; done; echo
4 10 8 7 1 6 3 5 2 9
```